# How to find average from pivot table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to capture transactions per hour between given ranges. And i need to identify the last one week of average transactions.

here i am facing some issue.

```
    Below is my trail:
    [Table Structure]
    [Current Result]
    [Query]

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATE, TimeStamp) AS [Date],
    DATEPART(hour,TimeStamp) AS [Hour],
    sum(CASE WHEN Result = 'F' THEN 1    ELSE 0    END) AS FAIL 
     FROM TableName 
     where  TimeStamp between '2018-05-12 00:00:00' and '2018-05-24 23:00:00'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,TimeStamp), DATEPART(hour,TimeStamp)) AS HourlyData 

    PIVOT( SUM(FAILS) FOR [Hour] IN (    [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
    ) AS DatePivot
    -- avg([Hour]  ) over(partition by DATEPART(hour,TimeStamp)) Avg_Item

[Table strcture,Current result and expected result][1]
```

Anybody please correct me how to find average? Tried with `Over` clause but not sure which column I need to add in the script.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeQYY.jpg
```

Comment: What are the records present in the table? I see only one record in the snapshot. Also can you explain average value in expected result? 1, 1 and 3 resulting into 2.5??

Comment: Rajesh Bhat: For every hour there will be couple of failures in the database. Assume today at 2PM there are 5 failures. now need an avearage since last 3-5 days at the same time(2PM) .14th 1 failure, 15th 1 failure,16th 3 failures. so the average is 1+1+3/3days=1.5 . so if i receive 5 failures then there is some problem in the system.

Comment: Did below answer help? If yes, please mark as answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Below code should give you the expected result.

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT 
        CONVERT(DATE, TimeStamp) AS [Date],
        DATEPART(hour,TimeStamp) AS [Hour],
        sum(CASE WHEN Result = 'F' THEN 1.0    ELSE 0.0    END) AS FAIL 
         FROM #tmp 
         where  TimeStamp between '2017-01-10 00:00:00' and '2018-05-24 23:00:00'
        GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,TimeStamp), DATEPART(hour,TimeStamp)) AS HourlyData 
        PIVOT( SUM(FAIL) FOR [Hour] IN ( [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
        ) AS DatePivot
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), TimeStamp) AS [Date],
    DATEPART(hour,TimeStamp) AS [Hour],
    sum(CASE WHEN Result = 'F' THEN 1.0   ELSE 0.0    END) AS FAIL 
     FROM #tmp 
     where  TimeStamp between '2017-01-10 00:00:00' and '2018-05-24 23:00:00'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),TimeStamp), DATEPART(hour,TimeStamp)) AS HourlyData 
    PIVOT( SUM(FAIL) FOR [Hour] IN ( [8], [9], [10],[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])
    ) AS DatePivot
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AVERAGE',AVG([8]),AVG([9]),AVG([10]),AVG([11]),AVG([12]),AVG([13]),AVG([14]),AVG([15]),AVG([16]),AVG([17]),AVG([18]),AVG([19]),
        AVG([20]),AVG([21]),AVG([22]),AVG([23])
FROM CTE
```